# Expose some public pages behind WF - Federation

Tags: asp.net

I have setup WF - Federation though my web config protected my site behind Federated Authentication. When ever someone comes to the site they are redirected to log-in, and afterward they are returned to the site.

I would like to expose a splash page that users could hit and then proceed to the secure area. I haven't seen any examples of how to white list routes though the web config.

So how is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical custom location with anonymous authorization should work here as well as usually:

```
 <location path="splash.aspx">
    <system.web>
       <authorization>
          <allow users="*" />
       </authorization>
    </system.web>
 </location>
```